# Repeated t-test based on a condition for multiple times

Tags: r

I wanna perform the two-sample t-test based on age group repeatedly by F1 ~ F4.
Here is my data (real data set has more than 1000 rows). I collect data from 4 age groups from two countries.

```
group country   F1   F2   F3   F4
  1        1     0.2   0.2  1.3  7.1
  2        2     1.3   0.1  2.1  1.1
  1        2     2.1   4.6  0.2  3.2
  4        1     0.4   0.1  2.5  5.1
  3        1     0.1   0.8  3.7  4.4
```

I tried to use the group_by function to divide the group
and use the lapply function to do the t-test multiple times
But it doesn't work.
The first error is '.[-c(1, 2, 3)]' is not a function, character or symbol.
Here I want to exclude the first three columns which don't need to do a t-test.

```
df_M %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  lapply(.[-c(1,2,3)], function(x) t.test(x ~ .$country))
```

So I tried performing the group_by function first, like:

```
test <- df_M %>%
  group_by(group)
t.test <- lapply(test [-c(1,2,3)], function(x) t.test(x ~ test $country))
```

But the second issue comes, I didn't get what I want but the t-test between countries 1 & 3 for F1~F4, which are not further based on different groups.

It can be solved if I create different data frames by groups, such as:

```
G1 <- filter(df_M, df_M$group == 1)
G1_ttest <- lapply(G1[-c(1,2,3)], function(x) t.test(x ~ G1$country))
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? Do you get an output that you don't expect? If so, what are you comparing it to? If you were to write out the commands you want to run out by hand, what would that look like? Is looks like group 2 only has one country. What exactly are you testing in that case?

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your questions. I update the description. About what I want to test is that I want to know the differences of 4 factors in each group between 2 countries. For example, in group 1,  are there significant differences between countries 1 & 3 of F1.

Comment: Well it's not really possible to test that hypothsis for the sample data you provided since some groups have only one country. Please change your sample data so it's actually possible to test that particular hypothsis or describe what should happen in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `lapply` with `group_by`. The `group_by` verb will only work with `dplyr` commands. Base R functions like `lapply` will not consider that extra attribuite. It appears you are trying to do something like

```
df_M %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(across(F1:F4, ~list(t.test(.x ~ country))))
```

If you really wanted a named list at the end, you would also add

```
df_M %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(across(F1:F4, ~list(t.test(.x ~ country)))) %>% 
  select(F1:F4) %>% 
  as.list()
```